# Filtering factors in r using dplyr

Tags: dplyr, filtering

I have a dataset that I need to filter some data to analyze them separate.
My dataset has two Sites (DRP, PSP), three Gradients (H,M,L), and 6 Func_Groups.

```
Site Plot_ID Gradient Func_Group Count
1  DRP       1   Medium      Forbs    15
2  DRP       1   Medium Graminoids    11
3  DRP       1   Medium      Woody     9
4  DRP       1   Medium    Legumes     1
5  DRP       1   Medium      Liter     0
6  DRP       1   Medium       Bare     0
```

I need to filter one functional group and one site at the time to analyze it separately e.g. DRP Graminoids, DRP Forbs, DRP Legumes etc.

The problem is Site, Gradient, and Func_Group are factors and the function "filter" from dplyr package doesn't let me do it.
this is the line of code I used

```
Graminoids<-DRP.PSP.Func.Div.4m %>%
            filter(Site,"DRP"|Func_Group,"Graminoids")
```

And it gave me this error:

```
Error in `filter()`:
! Problem while computing `..1 = Site`.
✖ Input `..1` must be a logical vector, not a factor<83d5e>.
```

So my question is what function should I use to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1):

This code will get filter your data to only include observations that are "DRP" site *and* "Graminoids" Func_Group. Note that in your original example, you used "|" which means "OR" in R syntax, whereas "&" is used for "AND". Additionally, you need to use "==" to evaluate whether some is "equal to".

```
base::library(package = dplyr)

df <- utils::read.table(text =
  "Site Plot_ID Gradient Func_Group Count
  1  DRP       1   Medium      Forbs    15
  2  DRP       1   Medium Graminoids    11
  3  DRP       1   Medium      Woody     9
  4  DRP       1   Medium    Legumes     1
  5  DRP       1   Medium      Liter     0
  6  DRP       1   Medium       Bare     0",
  header = TRUE
)

df_filtered <- df |>
  dplyr::filter(Site == "DRP" & Func_Group == "Graminoids")

base::print(df_filtered)
```

Produces this filtered dataframe:

```
  Site Plot_ID Gradient Func_Group Count
2  DRP       1   Medium Graminoids    11
```

See the [examples and documentation](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/filter.html) on the `dplyr::filter()` function.